# pick up specific words from string using regex match

Tags: regex

I want to pick up specific word from below string using regex. I need to match query and secondstring. I have regex like

```
(\w+)\s*\{([^(]+)\((.*)

{"querys":"query{secondstring(input:{
```

For above it works fine. But i will have to match below also using same regex.

```
{"query":"query{helloworld {sdsd
```

You can see that there is a space and { instead of (.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the reason you don't match the second sample is that there's no `(` in it, while your pattern contains a `\(` by the end. Maybe you would like to use [`(\w+)\s*\{([^({]+)\s*[({](.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/mJuxZA/1) ?

Comment: Change `[^(]+` to `[^({]+` or `[^({\s]+` if you don't want match spaces at all.

Comment: Or perhaps `"(\w+)\s*{([^{(]+)` to match query and the second string [demo](https://regex101.com/r/buKyi9/1)